# plotting repeating value in r

Tags: r, plot

I have a value. I want to plot this value on Y-Axis against 126 values (2 to 127) on X-Value.
How can I do that?

If I use this code:

```
plot((2:127),FF)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
plot((2:127), rep(FF, 126))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, too.

```
plot(cbind(2:127, FF))
```